# Python / rdflib HTTP server for sparql endpoint

Tags: sparql, rdflib

Is there a capability for or example of creating a Sparql HTTP endpoint with rdflib? We would want it to follow the spec and be able to return json and/or csv formats. This would mostly be for POC usage. It would also be possible to use Javascript/Node.
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-web

Answer (score 2):

You might try https://github.com/rdflib/pyLDAPI. It's been touched much more recently than https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-web and there are some public examples of it to follow, e.g. https://geofabricld.net. Also, the SKOS-specific tool [VocPrez](https://github.com/RDFLib/VocPrez/) uses it under the hood.

As of earlier this year, pyLDAPI implements the W3C's [Content Negotiation by Profile](https://www.w3.org/TR/dx-prof-conneg/) specification which is, I suppose, the latest an greatest Linked Data API-relevant specification, although it's not just for Linked Data APIs.

Feel free to contact me directly if you need more of a hand with this.